# Scope of JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript

Quick question about JSON in general, say I had:

```
var foo = {
  a: null,
  init: function() {
    this.a = document.getElementById(...);
  }
}
```

This will give have a with null. Is there anyway to go outside this scope and get the document element other than doing it externally via foo.a = document.getElementById(...)?

EDIT: Changed title more appropriately.

I am calling foo.init(), but when I do this, say I have:

and then I call init.foo() which contains this.a = document.getElementById('test') it seems to return NULL, perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Comment: That is not JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any JSON in this question. Could you describe what you're trying to do a little more clearly?

Comment: @dan04's correct, this is JSON, as long as you remove the N.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the question is. Do you want to execute the function without referring 'a'?

Comment: are you actually calling foo.init()?

Comment: Please show how you're calling `init`. That might make your question more clear.

Comment: It was already said, but I say it again: This is not JSON, it is a normal JavaScript object defined with object literal notation. See also http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:

```
var foo = {
  a: null,
  init: function() {
    this.a = document.getElementById('test');
  }
}

foo.init();
console.log(foo.a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwhxN/

Answer (score 1):

This is not [JSON](http://json.org/). JSON is a lightweight data exchange format which is similar to JavaScript (hence the name *JavaScript Object Notation*). This is just regular JavaScript.

Nonetheless, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. In your example, if you ran `foo.init()`, then `foo.a` would be reassigned to `document.getElementById(...)`. If you're wanting to get the global object, then there's this old trick:

```
var foo = {
    a: null,
    init: function () {
        (function () {
            this.test = 1;
        })();
    }
};
```

In that example, running `foo.init()` will create the **global** variable `test` with a value of `1`. If you mean getting the `document` element, as you said, then it is just as easy as referencing `document` (just as you did). If you mean changing the value of `foo.a` inside of `foo.init`, then there are only the two methods of using `foo.a` and `this.a` that I'm aware of.

However, I could be completely missing the mark...

Answer (score 1):

It matters how the function is invoked. The following usage will behave as expected:

```
foo.init();
```

In the above example the value of `this` inside `init` will be `foo`, so `foo.a` will be modified. However, be careful. This:

```
var fn = foo.init;
fn();
```

...will not behave as expected. The object receiving the message to execute `foo` in this case is the `window` object, so the value of `this` inside `init` will be `window`, and `foo.a` will not be modified (`window.a` will be).

You have complete control over the value of `this` inside your functions. In other words, you control the *context* in which your functions execute. This is done using JavaScript's call/apply: For example, what if we did this:

```
var someObj = {};
foo.init.apply(someObj);
```

In this example, `init` will be executed in the context of `someObj`, which means that `someObj.a` will be modified.

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply